# Posting to Tumblr via Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth, tumblr

I'm having a ridiculously difficult time trying to connect to the Tumblr API via Node. I can pull data all day long, but keep getting 401 errors when posting, even though I have completed the OAuth handshake.

```
var Tumblr = require('tumblrwks'),
    OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;

var oa = new OAuth(
  'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token',
  'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token',
  keys.consumerKey,
  keys.consumerSecret,
  "1.0A",
  null,
  "HMAC-SHA1"
);

oa.getOAuthRequestToken(
  function(error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results) {
    if (error) return 401;
    keys.accessToken = oauth_token;
    keys.accessTokenSecret = oauth_token_secret;

    tumblr = new Tumblr({
      consumerKey: keys.consumerKey,
      consumerSecret: keys.consumerSecret,
      accessToken: keys.accessToken,
      accessSecret: keys.accessTokenSecret
    }, blogName);
  }
);

exports.new = function(req, res) {
  tumblr.post('/post',
    { type: 'text', tags: 'api,test', title: 'Test API Post', body: 'It works!' },
    function(err, json){
      if(err) {
        console.log("Error creating post\n", err);
      } else {
        res.send(json);
      }
    }
  );
};

exports.posts = function(req, res) {
  tumblr.get('/posts', function(err, json){
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error getting posts\n", err);
    } else {
      res.send(json);
    }
  });
};
```

On server launch, the OAuth request is made, and I get back an OAuth Token, OAuth Secret, and Results = "{ oauth_callback_confirmed: 'true' }". These tokens are included in the subsequent POST request, but the response I get back is:

```
[Error: {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}]
```

GET requests are fine, and return all the posts, as expected. I can't, however, get new content to post. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Steve.  My code currently looks very close to yours and I'm getting the same error.  Did you ever fix it?

Comment: Not yet. I am currently working with the API Tech Team at Tumblr to sort this issue out. I will provide an update when the issue has been resolved. Hopefully it will help with your trouble, as well.

Comment: You're only using the request token here! You need to get an access_token and access_secret and then authenticate... I kinda hacked something together, but I've posted it as an answer.  The code below is literally what I'm using right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're only using the request_token.  You haven't completed the authentication.  Many of the get requests don't require authorization, so you're not running into problems there.  Here is how I got my authentication to work.

First, initialize your OAuth object with your client keys

```
OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth;
var tumblr = require('tumblr.js');

var consumer= new OAuth("https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token",
                  "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token",
                  your_client_key,
                  your_secret_key,
                  "1.0A",
                  "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/callback",
                  "HMAC-SHA1");
```

Then get a request token.

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
     consumer.getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret){
        if (error) {
            res.send("Error getting OAuth request token: " + error, 500);
        } else {
            oauthRequestToken = oauthToken,
            oauthRequestTokenSecret = oauthTokenSecret;
            res.redirect("http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + oauthRequestToken);
        }
    }); 
};
```

The user is directed to Tumblr, where they have to grant access to your application.  Once you are authenticated, you grab an access token.

The callback function is called when Tumblr redirects the user back to you.

```
exports.callback = function(req, res){  
    consumer.getOAuthAccessToken(oauthRequestToken, oauthRequestTokenSecret, req.query.oauth_verifier, function(error, _oauthAccessToken, _oauthAccessTokenSecret) {
        if (error) {
            res.send("Error getting OAuth access token: " + error, 500);
        } else {
        //you want to save these, preferably linked to your user's id
        console.log(_oauthAccessToken);
        console.log(_oauthAccessTokenSecret);
        var client = new tumblr.Client({
        consumer_key: T_C_K,
        consumer_secret: T_S_K,
        token: _oauthAccessToken,
        token_secret: _oauthAccessTokenSecret
        });
        client.userInfo(function (err, data) {
              res.send('You are signed in. welcome '+data.user.name);
        });
        }
    });
};
```